# Redirect domain to subdomain internally with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to internally redirect the domain redacted.org to redacted.redacted.org. So, when people go to redacted.org they see redacted.redacted.org without having the address changed in their adresses bar.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No it's called an internal redirect in Apache and is actually possible without making the client aware of the redirect in any way.

Comment: @Luc - Ok; sounds like you have another way, one I've not heard of or dealt with. You could, of course, put that in an answer. `;)`

Comment: @Luc a redirect across domains is _not_ possible without informing the user, absent some kind of proxy.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ever heard of mod_rewrite?

Comment: @Luc - `mod_rewrite` is not technically a *redirect*. And, uh, I imagine he has.

Comment: @Luc Yes I have.  You cannot rewrite a domain without doing an actual redirect. You can rewrite internally on the same domain to your heart's content.  If the subdomain is merely a v-host on the same server, then yes you can rewrite into that directory, but if it is _not_ the same server then you _must_ redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `.htaccess` file should be placed in the root of redacted.org:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) /path/to/redacted.redacted.org
```

PS. Seeing the comments on the question, I'm not the only one to wonder what attempts you've made yourself at solving the problem before posting it.

Comment: This may be entirely what the OP meant, but the terminology used doesn't suggest this, since it's not a *redirect*. I will say, though, this could very be what the OP intended; without more information from that person, it's hard to say.

Comment: @JaredFarrish It does what he requests: display the subdomain's site instead of the root, while not displaying that in the address bar. Guess this is how he meant it.

Comment: @LuisFilipeÁvila In that case, a reverse proxy is what you are looking for.